# nginx return 405 when post request hit limit_req_zone

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-405, ngx-http-limit-req-module

nginx config

```
http {
   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit:50m rate=10r/m;
   server {
      server_name xxx;
      error_page 503 @503;
      location @503 {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
      }
      error_page 405 @405;
      location @405 {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
      }
   }
}
```

so when request nums hit the limit,if method is GET it returns 503 while method is POST it returns 405, I don't understand why POST method returns 405, and why 405 error_page does not rewrites to 503.html as I set

Answer (score 0):

don't return or rewrite a static content but just return 503 status_code when method is POST then fix:

```
http {
   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit:50m rate=10r/m;
   server {
      server_name xxx;
      error_page 503 @503;
      location @503 {
         if ( $request_method = POST ) {
             return 503 '{"code":503,"message":"Service Temporarily Unavailable"}';
         }
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth to include `add_header Content-Type 'application/json' always;` into the `if` statement. To rewrite any URI you can use something more simple like `rewrite ^ <string>` (you definitely do not need any capture group there).